# Vector Math functions for midpoint calculation

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to find the midpoint of a two 3D vectors (A and B). I believe it should be VectorA + VectorB/2 will give the midpoint. But how would I use create a fucntion that returns the midpoint like this V3D Midpoint(V3D A, V3D B); if I have a class like this:

```
class V3D
{
public:

V3D(); 
V3D(float x, float y, float z);
~V3D();

V3D operator+( const V3D& V ) const; 
V3D operator(const V3D& V ) const; 
V3D operator*( float Scale ) const; 
V3D operator/( FLOAT Scale ) const; 

float dot( const V3D& V ) const; 
V3D cross( const V3D& V ) const; 
V3D Normal() const; // this vector's unit vector
float Size() const; // magnitude of this vector

private:
float X, Y, Z;
};
```

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking us to write the solution for you? SO is not a code writing service. What have you done to solve it on your own (please show those efforts).

Comment: One can define a mid point of a vector as (start location + end location)/2. How do you define the mid point of two vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this work ?

```
V3D Midpoint(const V3D& A, const V3D& B)
{
return (A + B) / 2.0;
}
```

This is simply writing in code what you specified in the question.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was all that was needed. I was confused by the operator in the class which I had not seen before